# Condición para saber cuándo se acabo el método de ordenamiento Quicksort- JAVA

Tags: java

Realicé el método de ordenamiento Quicksort, con un contador que va aumentando por cada paso:

```java
public static void ordenamientoRapido(int[] arreglo,int izq,int der) throws Excepcion {
        //Inicialmente: izq=0, y der= El tamaño del arreglo-1
        int pivote=arreglo[izq];
        int i=izq; 
        int j=der; 
        int aux;
         if(der+1==0) {
             throw new Excepcion("Lista vacía");
         }else {
             while(i<j){            
                 while(arreglo[i]<=pivote && i<j) {
                     i++; 
                 }
                 while(arreglo[j]>pivote) {
                     j--;         
                 }
                 if (i<j) {                                            
                     aux= arreglo[i];                  
                     arreglo[i]=arreglo[j];
                     arreglo[j]=aux;
                 }
               }
               arreglo[izq]=arreglo[j];
               arreglo[j]=pivote;
               imprimir(arreglo);
               contador++;

               if(izq<j-1) {
                  ordenamientoRapido(arreglo,izq,j-1);
               }
               if(j+1 <der) {
                  ordenamientoRapido(arreglo,j+1,der);  
               }
               if(condicion) {
                    System.out.println("Pasos: "+contador); 
                    System.out.println();
                    contador=0;
               }
         }
    }
```

Lo que sucede es que entiendo de forma gráfica el procedimiento de Quicksort, pero no encuentro una condición para cuando se termina de ordenar el arreglo.**Deseo saber qué condición colocar en el último if para lograr que se imprima la cantidad de pasos una vez el arreglo quedó ordenado.**

Comment: Es un algoritmo recursivo. No saldrás de la primera invocación al método hasta que no haya acabado su ejecución. Así que al salir del método.

Comment: ¿No hay alguna forma de hacerlo en el método?, estoy usando ese contador en otros métodos de ordenamiento

Comment: Necesitarías saber el nivel de profundidad de la recursividad, para saber si estás en la primera llamada del método (que es la que te interesa) o en alguna de las siguientes. Puedes hacerlo pasando un parámetro que vayas incrementando.

Comment: o, sencillamente, la primera llamada no es recursiva sino que llama a un método privado "ordenamientoRapido2", que es idéntico a este. Así, solo en "ordenamientoRapido" tienes el "primer nivel" y este código (y de hecho no necesitas ni un if).

Comment: Ohhh, genial, no se me habría ocurrido, gracias